# Android - Check if file extension is .mp4

Tags: java, android, file-extension

I want to check if the user entered the extension `.mp4` and if it was entered correctly. I know I can do something like this:

```
if (Rename[0].indexOf(".") > 0) {

}
```

But the problem with this is that it just checks if there is more than one character entered, so if `.mp5` has been entered or any incorrect extension, it would be accepted.

here is the context in which I want to use it:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Rename[0] = editText.getEditableText().toString();

            if (Rename[0] != null){

            //This is where I want to check if the extension has been correctly entered

            }
}
```

So my question is:

How can I get the text from `Rename{0}`, this has already been done, and check if the file extension `.mp4` has been entered correctly, if it has not, then add it, else if it was entered (correctly) ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if (Rename[0].endsWith(".mp4")) {

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

do this by below code :

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Rename[0] = editText.getEditableText().toString();

            if (Rename[0] != null){

              if(Rename[0].contains(".mp4"){
             //do what you want to do here
             }

            }
}
```